# Async method in WebApi causes IIS ExecuteRequestHandler to hang

Tags: c#, iis, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method in my WebApi 2 Controller

```
[Route("document/{documentGuid:Guid}/basic")]
[DocumentName("label")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> BasicDocument(Guid documentGuid)
{
    byte[] data = await _documentsGenerator.CreateDocument(documentGuid);
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = string.Format("document-{0}-basic.pdf", documentGuid)
    };
    return result;
}
```

When I call it from the browser to download the file, I get the file, but the request is still pending in the IIS workers list:

[image]

If I remove the async/await code from the method, everything works fine. It also doesn't matter what kind of async operation I'm performing. As long as I'm using `await SomeMethod()` the `ExecuteRequestHandler` hangs. What might be the cause?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://www.leansentry.com/Guide/IIS-AspNet-Hangs)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this is that some of the runtime is not running in .NET 4.5 (or newer).

Please ensure:

1. That your application is targeting .NET 4.5 or newer.
2. That your application has an attribute `httpRuntime.targetFramework` in its `web.config` set to the appropriate value (e.g., `4.5`).

Comment: Yes, I does target .NET 4.5 and has the targetFramework attribute in Web.config. However it might be related to IIS or Windows, since this error happens on Windows 8.1 with VS 2013, while on Windows 10 with VS 2015 the problem does not occur